# Weston compositor x11-backend doesn't found

Tags: xorg, wayland

I have an embedded system where I want to run weston compositor to use wayland. I was able to build the weston app and went I launch it from my system I got the following error:

```
#./weston 
Date: 2016-09-02 UTC
[15:08:36.341] weston 1.5.0
               http://wayland.freedesktop.org/
               Bug reports to: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Wayland&component=weston&version=1.5.0
               Build: 1.4.93 configure.ac: Bump version 1.4.93 (2014-05-12 12:51:52 -0700)
[15:08:36.342] OS: Linux, 3.10.61-ltsi-d6cx, #2 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 8 13:16:40 CDT 2016, x86_64
[15:08:36.342] warning: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR "/tmp" is not configured
correctly.  Unix access mode must be 0700 (current mode is 777),
and must be owned by the user (current owner is UID 0).
Refer to your distribution on how to get it, or
http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/basedir-spec
on how to implement it.
[15:08:36.343] Starting with no config file.
[15:08:36.344] Loading module '/usr/lib/weston/x11-backend.so'
[15:08:36.344] Failed to load module: /usr/lib/weston/x11-backend.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
#
```

I have looked for the library x11-backend.so in all places and I didn't find it. I built weston using buildroot.

Any help to work around this problem will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what was the problem. Buildroot set in the weston.mk file, under the packages directory, the following options:

```
WESTON_CONF_OPT = \
    --with-dtddir=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/share/wayland \
    --disable-egl \
    --disable-simple-egl-clients \
    --disable-xwayland \
    --disable-x11-compositor \
    --disable-drm-compositor \
    --disable-wayland-compositor \
    --disable-headless-compositor \
    --disable-weston-launch \
    --disable-colord
```

So as you can see, buildroot is taken off a lot of backends and weston-launch.

What I did then was comment part of that configuration as follow:

```
WESTON_CONF_OPT = \
    --with-dtddir=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/share/wayland \
#   --disable-egl \
#   --disable-simple-egl-clients \
#   --disable-xwayland \
#   --disable-x11-compositor \
#   --disable-drm-compositor \
#   --disable-wayland-compositor \
#   --disable-headless-compositor \
#   --disable-weston-launch \
    --disable-colord
```

And then I did

```
make weston-reconfigure
```

at some point make stop with an error due to pam package wasn't installed, so I installed it:

```
make linux-pam
```

and when that finished I did again

```
make weston-reconfigure
make weston
```

And problem solve!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to launch Weston with the X11 backend, but it looks like you haven't compiled the X11 backend. In any case, you don't want to use the X11 backend, as the Wayland display system is a replacement for the older Xorg system. You will want to launch Weston with the `weston-launch` command, which will run Weston with the DRM backend. See the section *Running Weston* at the bottom of https://wayland.freedesktop.org/building.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are right, at the end I don't want to use X11 with wayand, but I don't have either weston-launch built as well I don't have x11-backend.so built. The problem is that I don't know why buildroot is not building them.